# Bootstrap Navbar placing overtop Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following page menu

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" >
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-11 col-xs-offset-1" >

        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="navbar-brand">
             My logo
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <div class="navbar-right">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><div class="some_class" style="margin: auto;"></div></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also I have the following bootstrap carousel:

```
<div id="carusel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">


            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox" >

                <div class="active item" id="item1">
                    <img class="new" src="../image1.png"  style="min-height:496px;max-height: 896px;width: 100%" alt="...">


                    <div class="carousel-content">

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-11  col-xs-offset-1"  >

                                <div class="col-md-8  center-block"  >
                                Content1
                                 </div>

                               <div class="col-md-8  center-block"  >
                                Content2
                                 </div>
               </div>
           </div>
```

Menu consists of left part and right part.
There is a content placed over my carousel. 
The content consists of left column and right column.
How can the left column be placed just below the left part of menu(the same X coordinate), and the right column be placed just below right part of menu. (The same Y coordinate).
Telling in another words:
How can I place "Content 1" just below the "My Logo" of menu. I mean place them in a way, that they both will have the same x coordinate, the same left margin. 
So I want to align content of my carousel according to bootstrap menu.

Comment: You might consider making a jsfiddle so we can see the issue

Comment: I just want to place the corresponding content of bootstrap carousel below the bootstrap menu left and right sections :) Thanks muchin advance :)